# Audio Doesn't work with Safari 11(Mac OS)

Tags: macos, audio, safari, twilio, codec

I have migrated the code from version 1+ to version 2+ using [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/migrating-1x-2x).

As I have search out for the issue is **Audio Doesn't work with Safari 11(Mac OS)** And I get the idea about the codec.

So, I have set the below codec for audio and video

```
preferredAudioCodecs: ['isac', 'OPUS']

if (isChrome() || isFirefox()) {
    connectOptions.preferredVideoCodecs = ['VP9', 'H264'];   } else {
    connectOptions.preferredVideoCodecs = ['H264', 'VP9'];   }
```

Currently, this is running well with all browsers. But when I trying to test between chrome to safari. At times Audio is not working at both sides.

Comment: The "this" link talks about Twilio Verify and doesn't see to match up with your question. Which Twilio product are you referring to? I assume Programmable Video?

https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/developing-safari-11

Comment: Yes, Sorry about that. I have used [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/verify/migrating-1x-2x) link.

Comment: After checking this issue as long as and Twilio support. I have changed the codec for audio as below :

`preferredAudioCodecs: ['isac', 'opus', 'PCMA', 'PCMU']`

Now, audio is working fine with safari versions 11 and 12.